# Redirect https back to http in nginx with wildcard domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, rewrite

I have a top level domain example.com with a SSL wildcard cert attached to it, and a subdomain forum.example.com that I don't want SSL to be used on.

My problem is if I enter https://forum.example.com it gets trapped in a redirect loop rather than go to http//:forum.example.com, i've tried cleaning browser cache and stuff but to no avail, so it must be my config?

```
# Rid of the WWW
server {
server_name www.forum.example.com;
return 301 $scheme://forum.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Do php-fpm stuff on port 80
server {
server_name forum.example.com;
listen  80;
...
// locations
}

#redirect https requests
server {
listen *:443;
include global/ssl.conf;
server_name forum.example.com;
return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Does this look correct as far as removing the SSL from URL's to the example subdomain? As mentioned it just results in redirect loops.

**edit:** I think it was my browser cache between edits.

Comment: Does it redirect to https when you open http://forum.example.com ?

Comment: I'm going the other way, https.forum.example should redirect to http.forum.example, instead it goes into a loop. I'm looking to remove SSL from ever being used with the subdomain

Comment: I understand that, but still, when you load http does it redirect to https or it works just fine?
Can you give me the output of curl -I https ://forum.example.com ?

Comment: Have you tested with curl/wget?

Comment: Do you have STS headers in `example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, family commitments stopped me getting back debuging this. It was the right solution anyway. It was the browser cache holding the old edits/redirects.